# How to remove data using a link button

Tags: c#, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have an Attachment datagrid with a database source. 
The columns are: View | File Name | Remove.

How do I remove a data row on a link button click? Currently, the data row is deleted only from the datagrid, but not from the database.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gvwAttachmentFileOld" runat="server" KeyFieldName="Id" Width="520px" OnLoad="gvwFileAttachmentOld_Load" OnRowCommand="gvwAttachmentFileOld_RowCommand1">
<Columns>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="0" Caption="Action" Width="50px">
        <DataItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDownloadGridOld" runat="server" Text="View" OnClick="btnDownloadGridOld_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
        </DataItemTemplate>
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Id" FieldName="Id" Visible="false" VisibleIndex="1"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="File Name" FieldName="FileName" Width="450px"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="4" Caption="Action" Width="50px">
        <DataItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnHapusItemGridOld" runat="server" Text="Remove" CommandName="RemoveRow" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
        </DataItemTemplate>
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>                                                
</Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>

protected void gvwAttachmentFileOld_RowCommand1(object sender,     DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewRowCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandArgs.CommandName == "RemoveRow")
    {
    DataTable dtAttOld = (DataTable)Session["dtOld"];
    for (int i = 0; i < gvwAttachmentFileOld.VisibleRowCount; i++)
    {
        var id = e.CommandArgs.CommandArgument;
        string idx = Convert.ToString(id);

        DataRow[] dr = dtAttOld.Select(String.Format("Id = '{0}'", String.IsNullOrEmpty(idx) ? "0" : idx));

        if (dr != null)
        {
            dtAttOld.Rows.Remove(dr[0]);
            dtAttOld.AcceptChanges();
        }
    }
    Session["dtOld"] = dtAttOld;
    LoadGridAttachment();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide `LoadGridAttachment`?

Answer (score 0):

Removing a row from datagridview doesn't affect the datatable in the database. You need to write a query to remove data from the database..

If you are using sql, try something like getting the primary key or any unique column on the link button event and implement a command to remove the row..

It would be like

link button click event

```
int foo = int.Parse(yourDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

query to delete

```
delete from your table
where pKey = foo;
```